# 2003 Ford Focus 5 speed Stuck in Reverse

Tags: ford, focus, gears, manual-transmission

The shift lever is stuck in reverse and will not come out. I took out the shift tower to check the cable, and nothing appears to be missing or stuck. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: So running or not, clutch in, you can't pull it out of reverse?  With the car running, does the car actually travel in reverse like it should?